# Sentence alignment for dual-line bilingual paragraph in LaTeX

Tags: latex, translation, typeset

I would like to make a translation of entire paragraphs at a time for a large document, with the start of the new sentences aligning.  The following is almost what I want done, though it doesn't yet do the alignment for new sentences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\def\english{In the heart of the forest lived three little pigs who were brothers. The wolf always was chasing them in order to eat them. In order to escape the wolf, the pigs decided to make a house each. The smallest made his from straw, to finish first and go out to play. The middle one constructed a cottage from wood. Seeing that his little brother had finished already, he hurried to go and play with him. The oldest worked on his house of brick. 'You'll soon see what the wolf does with your houses,' he scolded his brothers but they were having a great time.}

\def\spanish{En el corazón del bosque vivían tres cerditos que eran hermanos. El lobo siempre andaba persiguiéndoles para comérselos. Para escapar del lobo, los cerditos decidieron hacerse una casa. El pequeño la hizo de paja, para acabar antes y poder irse a jugar. El mediano construyó una casita de madera. Al ver que su hermano perqueño había terminado ya, se dio prisa para irse a jugar con él. El mayor trabajaba en su casa de ladrillo. - Ya veréis lo que hace el lobo con vuestras casas - riñó a sus hermanos mientras éstos se lo pasaban en grande.}

\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
    \setstretch{3}
    \english
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \setstretch{3}
    \spanish
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample of dual line translation]

How can I automatically align new sentences?  For bonus points, how can I modify this method to manually indicate when one sentence in english aligns to two in spanish?

Comment: Are you willing to manually mark the end of a sentence with some flag? This might make the bonus point question, and the question in general easier.

Comment: Yes, for the purposes of the bonus question I am willing to mark the end of the sentence with a flag, only in cases where one sentence in english aligns to multiple in spanish (or vice versa).

Comment: I guessed this question was coming.  I think it's very hard, because the Tex82 engine doesn't offer you the opportunity to know how far across an hbox has been typeset (naturally enough, since the paragraph-breaking algorithm will vary the width of space), and because the amount of extra space needed on one line might depend on the next.  I won't say it *can't* be done, but I don't see how.  Luatex is another story, but right now it's unstable and not well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Charles.  I had never heard about Luatex, I'm looking into it now.

Comment: If you're willing to change the layout to be parallel columns (instead of interposed lines) there are some options: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=parallel

Comment: Hi Jouni, thanks for the comment.  The parallel column are a good point, but I'm pretty set on the interposed lines.  I'm hoping someone at SO will have the answer.

Comment: What about context-ruby? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/context-ruby.html#Docs  Can that be modified in some way to help provide a solution?

Comment: reposted here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/sentence-alignment-for-dual-line-bilingual-paragraph-translation-in-latex

Comment: A solution was found over at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/sentence-alignment-for-dual-line-bilingual-paragraph-translation-in-latex/2328#2328

Comment: @D W: You might actually want to post an answer linking to your question on tex.stackexchange.com, so that you can accept it and get this off the unanswered list.